# Can someone help me with this plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to make this exact plot but I can't seem to find the right color in the hexadecimal chart.

[image]

Also does anyone know how to change the labels on the y-axis as well. My values show up as 1e+07 instead of 10,000.

Here is the code I used to make my plot

The data is from the USAarrests data set from R.

```
p=ggplot(data=examdata,aes(Assault,Population))
p=p+geom_point(size=3,color="red",shape="asterisk")
p=p+geom_smooth(color="Purple",lty="dashed",fill="#71F563")
```

Here is the picture after I tried the color code you all found.

[Edited Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgJ2N.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCCzW.png)

I think I have to change the alpha on it, but I dont know how to do that with fill. Sorry if these questions have been asked.

Comment: I'm on a mac, built-in digital color meter says the green is #71F563 and the purple is   approximately #8F31E7. `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)`. I presume the downvote is because the y axis formatting question has certainly been asked before (and we're expected to search before adding a question), and the color question is unclear as to what you've tried.

Comment: Appreciate your help! Yea, i used the hexadecimal you gave me and it still seems too light, I will edit my post to show you.

Comment: I don't have your computer to know how it's set up to display colors. I suggest you google color picker and try some options for a better match.

Comment: @Jon Spring Appreciate your help! I think its the right color, just needs to be adjusted somehow. Is there a way to adjust the transparency levels for fill?

Comment: Replace #71F563 with #71F563E6 to make it that color with 90% opacity instead of 100%. See here for conversion: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

Comment: Just want to say thank you for helping me with this! You helped me out more than you know.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like a custom color palette to me. You can use an color picker tool (such as https://imagecolorpicker.com/) to see the exact hex. I tried it out and got this:

Green (CI): #7ef376

Purple (dashed line): #a251ef

Red (data points): #e93f33

Can you also show the code so we know what you did to get your y-axis?

Comment: Yes, I will make an edit showing my code. Thank you for your help! The color still seems to be lighter than what is in the picture so I will edit my post to show you both what I have.

Comment: I seems like the plot elements have some transparency to them that color picking would not give you the original color. You may need to manually fine-tuning it based on the picked hex.

Comment: Yes! I did that. Thank your help, this places has really cool people.